# Change the integral to polar coordinates and evaluate $\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{-\sqrt(1-x^2)}^{\sqrt(1-x^2)}(x)dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral:

> $$\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\,dy\,dx$$

By the looks of it, it seems that this is a semi-circle and the curve spans from $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$.

So I rewrote the integral as

$$\int_{-1}^{0}\int_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}x\,dy\,dx$$

Now I am not sure how to evaluate it.

$$\int_{-1}^{0}\Big[xy\Big]_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\,dx$$

$$\int_{-1}^{0}\left(\frac{x\pi}{2} - \frac{3x\pi}2\right)dx$$

If I continue in this way, I will get the wrong answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How did you changed the limits without effecting any other variable?

Comment: @ADITYA I wanted to change it to polar coordinates but I might be doing it wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a brief reminder. In the expression

$$
\int^a_b{\rm d}x~f(x)
$$

the variable $x$ changes from $a$ to $b$. So when you change the domain, you must change also the variables. More explictly: *$x$ does not change from $\pi/3$ to $\pi/2$*. What changes is the angle $\theta$, a whole new variable $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$. When you transform the variables, you get

$$
\int_{-1}^0{\rm d}x\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\rm d}y ~x = \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}{\rm d}\theta\int_{0}^1{\rm d}r~r(r\cos\theta)
$$

where the extra $r$ appears there because of the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). This last integral is pretty straightforward

$$
\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}{\rm d}\theta\int_{0}^1{\rm d}r~r(r\cos\theta) = \left(\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}{\rm d}\theta \cos\theta\right)\left(\int_{0}^1{\rm d}r~r^2\right) = -\frac{2}{3}
$$